# Problems with SVN svnlook command in Linux

Tags: svn

Here at the office I am logged into a Linux server.

From the command line I can execute the following command successfully

```
svn list -v https://svn.mycompany.com/rcs-sh/trunk/src
svn list -v https://svn.mycompany.com/rcs-sh/trunk/src | egrep $LOGNAME
svn cat https://svn.mycompany.com/rcs-sh/trunk/src/source_code_1.pl
```

However when I try to execute the command

```
svnlook info https://svn.mycompany.com/rcs-sh/trunk/src/source_code_1.pl
```

all I get is the error message

> `'https://svn.mycompany.com/rcs-sh/trunk/src/source_code_1.pl'` is a URL when it should be a path

I have tried a number of variations on my command and they all result in the same error message. How can I get "svnlook info" to work from the command line in Linux ?

Comment: The [Repository Maintenance](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html) tools need to operate on the raw repository files, that's why it asks for a path and rejects a URL.

Answer (score 3):

As [Álvaro González](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13508/%c3%81lvaro-gonz%c3%a1lez) noted, [`svnlook`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.html) is an administrative tool. What it does is that it prints:

> author, datestamp, log message size (in bytes), and log message,
>   followed by a newline character.

When used without explicit revision as in your question, [`svnlook info`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.info.html) defaults to showing information on the most recent version in the repository.

To get basically the same information from a working copy, you can use [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html):

```
svn log --limit 1 https://svn.mycompany.com/rcs-sh/trunk/src/source_code_1.pl
```

Example output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r20 | sally | 2003-01-17 22:56:19 -0600 (Fri, 17 Jan 2003) | 1 line

Made a change.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```